# Dropping Column in Pandas showing "not found in axis", even though df.keys() shows column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that I'd like to drop from a Pandas DataFrame. However, when attempting to drop the column, the error states that the column is not found. The code being used is below. The reason for flattening the index is due to it being a multi-index before flattening.

```
oldDf = pd.read_pickle('./df')
df = pd.DataFrame.copy(oldDf)
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
print(df.keys())
df = df.drop(["Exp, Exp"], axis=1)
print(df)
```

`df.keys()` result is below

```
Index([                                ('Exp', 'Exp'),
                                   ('Last Week', 'M'),
                                   ('Last Week', 'T'),
                                   ('Last Week', 'W'),
                                   ('Last Week', 'H'),
                                   ('Last Week', 'F'),
                                   ('This Week', 'M'),
                                   ('This Week', 'T'),
                                   ('This Week', 'W'),
                                   ('This Week', 'H'),
                                   ('This Week', 'F')], dtype='object')
```

Error when dropping is below.

```
KeyError: "['Exp, Exp'] not found in axis"
```

FYI, I have tried the following column names other than the one being used right now, and none of them have worked. I have also tried `axis=0`, which didn't help.

```
 ('Exp, Exp')
 ('Exp')
 '(Exp)'
 ('Exp', 'Exp')
```

Thanks!

Comment: does it work if you dont do `df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()` ?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work, it seems I have to drop the columns, then flatten the df. Thanks.